# Given two points of 4 or more dimensions is it possible to find a line equation?

Tags: python, numpy, math, coordinates

If i have two points like P1 = (x1, y1, w1, z1...) and P2 = (x2, y2, w2, z2...) is it possible to define a line equation? The points will always have the same number of dimensions, from 4 and 10.

What i want to do next is to use the equation to create other specific points on the line.

Comment: I started looking around numpy to find something but i don't remember enough math to find a solution. Maybe numpy.linalg.lstsq or polyfit have something to do with it?

Comment: Given two points it's always possible to construct a line through both of them. If you just want to add some points between them, you could use linspace in each dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a math question rather than a programming one, but it is easy to find the line between two points of any dimension using a [parametric equation / vector approach](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx)

```
p0 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) #any numbers, be it 4, 5 or n dimensions
p1 = np.array([3, 2, 4, 5])

# note that "p" can be any number from -inf to inf
straight_line_function = lambda p: p0 + p * (p1 - p0)
```